# Associate elastic IPs to ec2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

I have some(ie. 3) existing elastic IPs created in AWS earlier. I am trying to provision 3 AWS ec2 instances and associate those IPs to those newly created instances. I need to use those exisiting elastic IPs as they are white listed with my external partner for payment processes. I am not sure how to do that. I have the playbook below to create the ec2:

```
   - name: Provision a set of instances
     ec2:
        key_name: "{{ key_name }}"
        group_id: "{{ security_group }}"
        instance_type: "{{ instance_type }}"
        image: "{{ ami_id }}"
        wait: true
        exact_count: "{{ instances }}"
        count_tag:
            Name: Demo
        instance_tags:
            Name: "{{ application }}"
        region: "{{ region }}"
     register: ec2_instances

   - name: Store EC2 instance IPs to provision
     add_host:
       hostname: "{{ item.public_ip }}"
       groupname: ec2_instance_ips
     with_items: "{{ ec2_instances.tagged_instances }}"
```

The second task is get the ready to configure the instances.

I just need to associate the EIP to those instances next.

Thanks,
Philip

Comment: There's [ec2_eip](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/ec2_eip_module.html) module for that.

Comment: Did you refer this : http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/ec2_eip_module.html

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, pulled from one of my roles.

```
- name: associate with our instance
  ec2_eip:
    reuse_existing_ip_allowed: true
    instance_id: "{{ec2_instance}}"
    public_ip: "{{eip}}"
    state: present
    region: "{{ec2_region|default('us-east-1')}}"
    in_vpc: true
```

Comment: I will give this a try and see. Thanks for the tip

Comment: This works beautifully for one instance. But I have multiple instances that need to assign on EIP per instance.

Comment: That's what loops are for.

Comment: I tried to add loop, but looks like it loops through all the EIPs for one instance, then looks all the EIPs again on the second instance, not one EIP to one instance.

Comment: You need to loop over your instances and associate an EIP with them instead of the other way around. You'll have to figure out how to be deterministic with that assignment.

Comment: I tested it by using "with_indexed_items:" and it worked as expect. Thx.